# How to use two user inputs from two input boxes and divide them

Tags: vba, excel

I need to divide the two numbers that the user is inputting in the two InputBox's.  The number put in the first InputBox is the cost and the number put in the second InputBox is the weight.  I need to divide those two numbers to give me the price per unit.

```
    If response = vbNo Then
      retval = InputBox("Please Enter PO Cost")
        Number_1 = "InputBoxValue"

    retval = InputBox("Please Enter Net Weight")
        Number_2 = "InputBoxValue"

    Answer = Number_2 / Number_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cost / Weight` will give you price per unit:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim cost, weight, answer As Variant

    cost = InputBox("Please Enter PO Cost")
    weight = InputBox("Please Enter Net Weight")
    answer = cost / weight
    MsgBox "Price per Unit is: " & answer
End Sub
```